# Wie heißt das Phänomen, dass bestimmten Verben ein „zu“ vorangestellt wird?

Tags: grammar, terminology

In deutschen Sätzen wird Verben häufig ein *zu* vorangestellt oder in das Verb eingefügt. Beispiele dafür sind folgende Sätze:

- „Ich empfehle dir, den Kartoffelsalat *zu* probieren.“
- „Er half mir, den Acker um*zu*graben.“

Wie lautet die linguistische Bezeichnung dafür?

Comment: Wikipedia ist nicht konsistent; andere Artikel, wie auch viele Grammatiken, behandeln Infinitivgruppen nicht als Nebensätze.

Comment: Ich habe den Titel umformuliert, weil von _Phänomen_ gerade keine Infinitivgruppe abhängen kann. Anders zum Beispiel _die Angewohnheit_.

Comment: @chirlu Danke. Damit ist das Wort „Nebensatz“ aus der Frage Entfernt. Ich habe es nur benutzt, weil ich davon ausging, der Infinitiv mit „zu“ würde nur in Nebensätzen verwendet werden. Jetzt ist die Frage klarer.

Comment: Na ja, im eigentlichen Text der Frage steht es weiterhin. Wir könnten es aber auch dort herausnehmen.

Comment: *Jetzt* ist eine Frage draus geworden ;) Schließungsstimme zurückgezogen, +1 gegeben.

Comment: Ich behaupte, dass die zweite Form nur für trennbare Partikelverben funktioniert. Umgraben wegen *ich grabe um*, ist so eines, *probieren* nicht, *ausprobieren* dagegen schon.

Comment: Das _am_ in der *rheinischen* Verlaufsform funktioniert übrigens genauso wie das _zu_: „Ich bin den Kartoffelsalat *am* probieren“ und „Er ist den Acker um*am*graben“. Die standardsprachliche _am_-Verlaufsform erlaubt hingegen keine (eingeschobenen) Ergänzungen: „Ich bin am probieren (des Kartoffelsalats)“ und „Er ist am umgraben (des Ackers)“.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diese Kombination ist nicht mit beliebigen Verbformen möglich, sondern nur mit dem Infinitiv. Man spricht dann meist vom „Infinitiv mit *zu*“. Andere Bezeichnungen sind „*zu*-Infinitiv“ oder auch „mit *zu* erweiterter Infinitiv“; die letzte Variante ist allerdings unglücklich, weil sie zur Verwechslung mit dem Begriff „erweiterter Infinitiv mit *zu*“, den beispielsweise die Rechtschreibregeln benutzen, geradezu einlädt.